# Direct method in calculus of variation for some general spaces

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

In the book "Introduction to the calculus of variations" by Dacorogna, it states that
[image]

However, the space it works on is $u_0 + W^{1,p}_0 (\Omega)$. Can I have the existence of a minimizer in some general convex subspaces of a Hilbert space (or some better spaces)? May I have some references for this?

Comment: You could restrict this to $p=2$.

Comment: Oh, yes, shall we have something like this?

Comment: Why not. I do not understand your comment / question. The case $p=2$ is included in the above theorem, which is a HIlbert space setting.

Comment: The theorem stated only concerns the Hilbert space with Dirichlet boundary value in the sense of trace. I want some existence theroem on some general Hibert subset with some nice condition (I think at least convex subset)

Comment: Then you need to be more specific.